# Cannot start service www: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: java, php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I converted this [original](https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV/) project into a docker-compose project [here](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker) and followed a their setup [instructions](https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV/blob/master/INSTALLATION). It seems that I am not able to connect with the browser.

The [SQL file](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mysql/mgsv.sql) contains the database schema and looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE mgsv;
CREATE USER 'mgsv_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mgsvpass';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, CREATE, DROP ON mgsv.* TO 'mgsvuser'@'localhost';
use mgsv;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinfo` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` text NOT NULL,
    `hash` text NOT NULL,
    `synfilename` text NOT NULL,
    `annfilename` text NOT NULL,
    `url` text NOT NULL,
    `session_id` text NOT NULL,
    `annImage`   int(5) NOT NULL,
    `create_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

The [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mgsv
      - MYSQL_USER=mgsv_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mgsvpass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql123
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  www:
    build: ./mGSV 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mGSV/Dockerfile) contains PHP and all other tools setup and looks like this.

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
                openjdk-7-jdk \
                maven  \
        git \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git

# Move the folder 'mgsv' to DocumentRoot of Apache web server. By default, the DocumentRoot of Apache is /var/www/ (speak to the system administrator to know the exact DocumentRoot).
RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV \
    && mkdir tmp \
    && chmod -R 777 tmp

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV && sed -i.bak "s|'gsv'|'mgsv_user'|" lib/settings.php \ 
    && sed -i.bak "s|$database_pass = ''|$database_pass = 'mgsvpass'|" lib/settings.php \
    && sed -i.bak "s|cas-qshare.cas.unt.edu|localhost|" lib/settings.php

RUN cp /var/www/html/mGSV/Arial.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/

#Do not understand
#7. Cleanup scripts are provided to drop database synteny and annotation tables, remove entries from database table 'userinfo' and delete the folder containing image files which are older than 60 days. This task is accomplished by cron job to run the cleanup script every day. To create a cron job, use the command below:
#   shell> crontab -e

#At the last line of crontab, copy and paste the line below, and provide the exact path to mgsv/lib/cleanup.php
#   30 04 * * * /var/www/mgsv/lib/cleanup.php

#The script cleanup.php will be executed at 4:30 AM every morning.

#8. mGSV uses the mail function from PHP to send email to users. Speak to your system administrator to provide required information in the PHP configuration file called 'php.ini'.

#9. When installation completes, you can now open Install/index.php (i.e., http://<YOUR_SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME>/mgsv/Install/), which verifies prerequisites, database setup, and installation. YOUR_SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME refers to the domain name of your server.


RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \
    && tar -xzf mgsv-ws-server.tar.gz

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server \ 
    && mvn package

RUN cp -f /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server/target/ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \ 
    && echo "mgsv_upload_url=http://localhost/mgsv" > config.properties \
    && echo "ws_publish_url=http\://localhost\:8081/MGSVService" >> config.properties \
    && java -jar ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar &

#To stop the web service
#shell> ps aux | grep ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
#*Note the process id from the output*
#shell> kill -9 <process id>
```

This is the output which I got:

```
Successfully tagged mgsvdocker_www:latest
Starting mgsvdocker_www_1 ... 
mgsvdocker_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting mgsvdocker_www_1 ... error

ERROR: for mgsvdocker_www_1  Cannot start service www: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mgsvdocker_www_1 (37d78703b379b65521d9fc15d2d1d51379f7eee71f7dc912585e088d8bf1b4e9): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for www  Cannot start service www: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mgsvdocker_www_1 (37d78703b379b65521d9fc15d2d1d51379f7eee71f7dc912585e088d8bf1b4e9): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I am not quite sure whether I did a mistake in the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file or database configuration inside the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mGSV/Dockerfile#L16-L18).

By any chance, do anyone know what I am missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. See here on how to craft questions likely to get answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As a start you should post your code and error messages in the body of the question.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question as your suggested.

Comment: You've already got something running on port 8080!

Comment: I changed it to port 8000 but now I got this [output](https://gist.github.com/mictadlo/d7472b70356a47002b4f7d3097176ef9)

Comment: p.s. which IP address should I use?

Comment: looks like it's starting up fine now. Post another question with new problem.

Comment: Thank you all, I opened another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373422/error-1007-hy000-at-line-1-cant-create-database-mgsv-database-exists)